# strip_path and preserve_host attributes in KongIngress object. What do they do?

Tags: basic-authentication, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I have a `KongIngress` object configuration attributes regarding to Ingress resource which call to kong as an Ingress controller. I actually have this configuration:

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongIngress
metadata:
  name: echo-site-ingress
  namespace: hello-world
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "kong"
proxy:
  protocols:
    - http
    - https
#  path: /
route:
  methods:
    - POST
    - GET
  strip_path: true
  preserve_host: true
---
#My Ingress resource
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
    plugins.konghq.com: helloworld-customer-acceptance-basic-auth, hello-world-customer-acceptance-acl
  name: echo-site-ingress
  namespace: hello-world
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.bgarcial.me
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echo
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  tls: 
  - hosts:
    - hello-world.bgarcial.me
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod
```

The questions are:

What are doing in my `kind:KongIngress` object resource the `strip_path` and `preserve_host` attributes?

I read the documentation [here](https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/admin-api/#request-body-3), but it is not clear for me:

Regarding to `strip_path`  I see this one:

> When matching a Route via one of the paths, strip the matching prefix from the upstream request URL. Defaults to true.
>   but as we can see, I am not using the path  attribute inside my KongIngress object (I commented for illustration purposes about my question)

So, how `strip_path` attribute value is applied here?

It is because I am using in my Ingress resource the `path: /` attribute and my Ingress and my KongIngress resources are working together?

I really don't have a clue about it, but I would like to know how is this about behind scenes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `preserv_host` annotation is enabled the `host` header of the request will be sent as is to the Service in Kubernetes. Well explained in [the documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/0.10.x/proxy/#the-preserve_host-property).

`strip_path` can be configured to strip the matching part of your path from the HTTP request before it is proxied.

If it is set to `"true"`, the part of the path specified in the Ingress rule will be stripped out before the request is sent to the service. For example, when it is set to `"true"`, the Ingress rule has a path of  `/foo`  and the HTTP request that matches the Ingress rule has the path  `/foo/bar/something`, then the request sent to the Kubernetes service will have the path  `/bar/something`. 
So when you use `curl $YOUR_HOST/foo/bar/something`, under real path value in the output you will see `/bar/something`

And if set to `false` no path manipulation is performed and in your case can be changed to such as there is no manipulation to be done.

Comment: For kubernetes ingress controller you need to add `konghq.com/strip-path: true` to `annotations`